# How to make memoir not put bibliography on next recto page

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, page-breaking, memoir, subdividing

I am using two columns in a memoir document and when I place a bibliography using bibtex for some reason it ends up on the next recto page. I am writing a book with multiple chapters and I want each chapter to have it's own bibliography. Is it possible to set such a bibliography just as any other section and make it fit in the general two column flow of the text without having it breaking out on a new page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(The following minimal example works fine for me:) EDIT: Yes, it is possible to create section-bibliographies within book chapters. For convenience, I'm switching to the [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/biblatex.html) package which works together well with the `memoir` class. Note that when compiling my example, you have to run BibTeX several times unless you use makefiles like e.g. latexmk. For reference sections see section 3.5.4, for running BibTeX several times see section 3.10.1 of the `biblatex` manual.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{memoir}

\usepackage[refsection=chapter]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

\chapter{bla}

\section{blubb}

Some text \autocite{B02}.

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]

\chapter{foo}

\section{bar}

Some text \autocite{A01,B02}.

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]

\end{document}
```

(The filecontents environment is only used to include some external files directly into the example, so that it compiles. It is not necessary for the solution.)

Comment: Ah okej. You added the class parameter article. But I want to write a book with multiple chapters where each chapter has it's own bibliography. Sort of of like each chapter is an article. So I don't think adding article to the class is a solution for me.

Comment: @jonalv: No, it isn't -- but I lacked crucial information before (book with multiple chapters, each chapter to have its own bibliography) and am still lacking information now, namely how do you create your bibliographies.

Comment: I don't understand. I create the bib file using a mac program named bibdesk (I think) and then I use them much like you do in your example. What exactly is it you wonder?

Comment: @jonalv: For example, are the different section-bibliographies completely independent (which I'm assuming for now) or should labels like [1,2] be unique throughout the entire book? I've substantially reworked my example.

Comment: Aha yea I want each chapter to be stand alone. If the same citation are in multiple chapter they should be listed in multiple bibliographies and in most cases with different keys.

Comment: @jonalv: Different keys are standard. I've changed my example slightly to demonstrate this.